# Use GigE cameras in Kubernetes Pod by mounting the eth interface

Tags: kubernetes, ip-camera

I am looking for an elegant solution to mount GigE cameras in a Pod on K8s.

Basically, we have a single node k8s cluster with two ethernet interfaces: eth0 is configured for network traffic, eth1 has a link-local address and is attached to a switch with a bunch of GigE cameras.

If I use the "hostNetwork: true" option in a Pod, obviously I can see both interfaces and the camera libraries are able to discover the cameras automatically.

I want to get rid of this approach (as it prevents me from using services and ingress), and somehow only mount the link-local network interface with the cameras.

Any pointers to plugin frameworks that can do this, or any experience with it?
I already checked Akri, but it seems it only supports ONVIF detection for IP cams.